# How to auto roate the Azure AKS service principle

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am using Azure kubernetes service. While creating the AKS iam using service principle for autentication. I am deployed the AKS through power shell script.

```
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
   -Name aksname `
   -ResourceGroupName  $RESOURCE_GROUP `
   -TemplateFile $templateFileforakscluster `
   -TemplateParameterFile $parameterFileforakscluster `
   -existingServicePrincipalClientId $aksspid `
   -keyVaultName $KEYVAULT_NAME
```

Now i noticed that this SERVICE PRINCIPLE will expire after 1 year. There is a az cli command to rotate the service principle [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/aks/update-credentials#code-try-2)

When i deployed these in client environment, i want to  automatically rotate this using some code. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing around AKS to automate this, you'll need to schedule a job or a pipeline that take care of the renewal. With that said, to avoid having to do that you should consider using a [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity) instead of a Service Principle. The Identity is a kind of wrapper around a Service Principal that takes care of the renewal, thus it is easier to maintain.